# Run dotnet app in read-only docker container

Tags: c#, docker, .net-5

When dotnet app starts it tries to create pipes like `clr-debug-pipe-*` in `/tmp` directory. If `/tmp` is readonly, app will crash. Therefore I cannot run my app in container.

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/16141) one can set `COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics` environment variable to disable creating of these pipes, but memory dumps cannot be created, which is not good idea.

Is it possible to keep debugging pipes and readonly filesystem?

NOTE: My app runs in linux container, and there is just signle .net process there.

Comment: Also I do not understand why creating pipes blocks app startup, I thought you can create pipes in readonly filesystem.

Comment: Is this a linux container? If yes, why not simply use tmps for /tmp?

Comment: @Steeeve I want to have readonly-fs, so attacker cannot store file on disk as infection vector, therefore I don't want to use ramdisk etc.